# 0th lag order auto-covariance vs. Variance of variable

Tags: covariance

Is it true the 0th lag order auto-covariance of a variable Y_t is equivalent to the variance of that particular variable?

Answer (score 2):

For a weakly stationary process $\{Y_t\}$ with mean $\mu$, the $k$th lag [autocovariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) is

$$E\left[(Y_t - \mu)(Y_{t+k} - \mu)  \right]\,. $$

For $k = 0$, this is $E\left[(Y_t - \mu)^2\right] = Var(Y_t)\,. $

As a consequence, the 0th lag autocorrelation is 1.